# Double.Parse using specific culture

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, currency-formatting

I am trying here to parse a number using the Gabon currency formating.

The format uses "." for group separations and no decimals.

Here is an example :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");

            ci.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ".";
            ci.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 0;
            ci.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "CFA";

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;

            double.Parse("300.000", ci).ToString("C"); 
                    // gives me a FormatException
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something I am missing ?

Comment: Your comment is incomplete. It's not clear what you're expecting vs what you got. I will say that you should be using `decimal` instead of `double` for currency values though...

Comment: I was trying to parse it using the format the Gabonese use. Altough I am not able to parse it I always get an exception on the `double.Parse` part.

Comment: I added Robert's line and I was able to parse in a console application. It's not working using MVC's ModelBinder but I guess it's a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this:
            ci.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";

Answer (score 3):

In your case, you have to help .NET a little - when simply using `Parse` like that, it assumes you want to get a number. French culture uses `,` as a decimal separator and that is the reason your code throws an exception.

Try this, instead:

```
double.Parse("300.000", NumberStyles.Currency, ci).ToString("C");
```

Now, the string will get correctly parsed as currency, respecting the currency rules you have specified in the `ci` culture.

And - as others have  said, you should really use `decimal` when dealing with currency. Double is simply [not precise enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when).